# Reprocess a text file to consolidate lines containing Carriage Return (CR) characters into on-screen results

Tags: linux, bash, shell, perl, sh

Let's say I have a program (e.g. in *Perl*) that writes to `STDOUT` something like this:

```
print "123\t- 456";
print "\r+\n";
```

On my screen I see the following result:

```
123     + 456
```

However, when I redirect the output to a file `>output.txt`, such file will contain the following text:

```
123     - 456
        +
```

How can I "reprocess" such text file into the result same as shown on the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `col` command will do this with the `-b` option to replace backspaces with the last character written to a column.

```
col -b < output.txt
```

Comment: I love simple solutions. Thank you.